# Make rows to Columns in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I would like to change below data set to

```
with data as (select * from (values
             ('2018-08-09'::date,'cancel',35),
             ('2018-08-09'::date,'sum',25),
             ('2018-08-09'::date,'count',10)
             ) as v(date,row,number))
```

to this make rows to columns

```
        date           cancel      sum     count
        2018-08-09      35          25      10
```

How can I do that? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please Google for "SQL pivot query"

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tablefunc.html -> crosstab